# How to add a package in Julia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

While adding a new package I get the following error on Julia.

```
julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: SystemError: opening file C:\Users\ARPAN\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\registries\JuliaPro\C\Co
lor\Versions.toml: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `Color` should be `Colors` perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

This path looks to be missing `\` in the middle. Should be `...\ARPAN\.juliapro\...`.

One option is to set the environment variable `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` (executed at the command line):

```
set JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=C:\Users\ARPAN\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1

julia
```

And now once Julia is started install the packages. 
You can check that the above path is correct by running `versioninfo()` from Julia.

The question is why it did not work in the first place.
Most likely you have wrongly set one of `JULIA_*` environment variables. 
For a complete list see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/index.html.